# No solutions for django.core.management error

Tags: django, python-2.7

I know that this question has been asked and asked again, but none of the solutions seem to works for me. I'm using Django 1.9 with Python 2.7 on Windows 8.1. When I try to run the development server from my projects manage.py I get the `ImportError: No module named django core.management`.

- I only have one version of python
- I'm not using a virtual environment
- C:\Python27 and C:\Python27\Scripts are included in my path
- I can import django in python and get the version number
- I can import management from django.core in python
- my manage.py was created using pydev and begins with "#!/usr/bin/env python" as seems appropriate according to other answers
- I have already uninstalled and reinstalled django via pip

It is possible I might have messed something up when trying to change from 32 bit to 64 bit python in order to interface with Matlab.

Comment: Just gonna throw this out there, is it possibly a spelling mistake.

Comment: A hack: edit the manage.py file, and add the path to the os.environ

Comment: @AviahLaor could you please elaborate? you mean after the shebang? to the os.environ? Sorry if these questions seem naive, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start python from shell, the same way you did when the import works:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
'/the/python/path'
```

Copy this path, and in your manage.py add:

```
   sys.path.append('/the/python/path')
   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

Comment: My PYTHONPATH is not set to anything thus `os.environ['PYTHONPATH']` leads to a key error what is `/the/python/path/` supposed to point to? my django directory?

Comment: Tried sys.path.append?

Comment: So adding the path to my django directory seems to have fixed the first error but now I receive another error stating; 
`Error loading MYSQL module: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application` 
At this point I'm considering just deleting python completely and reinstalling it.

Comment: Btw - if you don't have to use Windows, Linux is better, IMHO, to install and work with django environment

Comment: Windows is certainly a cluster****, but unfortunately I don't have access to a Linux machine at this time

Comment: Virtual machine maybe? 1 hour installation and you are good to go

Comment: When I had given up hope and decided to uninstall python I noticed that a 64 bit version was installed and uninstalling this via the control panel solved my problem. I appreciate the help